# Do ApplicationData.localSettings get cleared when the app gets updated?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm working on modern Windows 8 app and wanted to figure out if  `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings` [(msdn doc is here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) get cleaned up when the app gets updated by the store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those settings are preserved across app updates, as are the roamingSettings and the contents of localFolder, roamingFolder, and tempFolder. In other words, performing an app update does not affect any of the appdata state, which makes perfect sense when you consider that many updates are minor bug fixes and should not in the least way require resetting or migrating existing state.

Do note that *uninstalling* an app and then reinstalling it will clean out localSettings, localFolder, and tempFolder. roamingSettings and roamingFolder will be restored provided that the user has had the app installed on another device within some reasonable period of time (unspecified, but something like 30 days).

It's also good to know that app state has its own versioning scheme through [ApplicationData.setVersionAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.setversionasync.aspx), and that an app update can choose, if it wants to migrate appdata from one version to another. Examples can be found in the [Application Data sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and details on uninstalling, that was the immediate next question that popped in my head.

Comment: You're welcome. I know that those questions always go together, hence my writing it out. (I talk about state as a whole in Chapter 10 of my free ebook, Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition (http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2). Those chapter that talk about WinRT are useful to anyone working with C#, VB, or C++, just that the code I show is in JS--but all the concepts and behaviors in WinRT are the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, your local settings will persist between app updates.